# What's it called?

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

So I was tasked to do this: it's a timekeeping web application for employees of our company.[image: how it should look]

Thing is I don't know what that red part is called. Yes I have seen it in blogs and news sites where news gets slided up(or down). But I don't know what's it called so I can't look for sample codes of it.

So, I'm asking: what is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @MaxiWheat: Seems like it. Yeah, I think its a sidebar. Though instead of links I'll be putting announcements/news taken from an SQL database there. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Are you talking about an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you means Coffin? http://fat.github.io/coffin/

> Coffin is a UI component built on top of the Skeleton framework. It
>   aims to provide a simple, collapsible left shelf. Coffin is fully
>   responsive and automatically collapses in mobile views - allowing you
>   to swipe away and toggle a nagivation in and out of view. It behaves
>   similar to facebook/path's navigation UI.